# Why is this alias in JPA named native query not working?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, alias

This one does not work:

```xml
<named-native-query name="FileSet.deleteByMemberId">
    <query>DELETE FROM FileSet f WHERE f.file_id = :fileId</query>
</named-native-query>
```

It gives this error:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'f WHERE f.file_id = 692' at line 1
```

While this statement works perfectly (without the table alias):

```xml
<named-native-query name="FileSet.deleteByMemberId">
    <query>DELETE FROM FileSet WHERE file_id = :fileId</query>
</named-native-query>
```

Why? I'm using MySQL and Hibernate as JPA provider.

Comment: You specified JPQL yet execute as SQL. SQL has no ":param" syntax. A parameter is a "?" in JDBC

Comment: This may be Hibernate specific, but Hibernate supports named parameters in native SQL: `Native SQL queries support positional as well as named parameters`. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8463

Comment: Yes, your code is non-portable, only usable in one JPA impl.

Comment: A valid point. But I'm confident we will see this feature in future JPA specifications. Positional parameters are a pain in the ass when dealing with really complex queries, where parameters appear multiple times. Until then, we have no plans to go for another JPA implementation. The same holds for databases. While it's important to stick as close to the SQL standard as possible, you sometimes have to use database specific features or dialects to achieve high-performance, maintainable queries. One always has to make decisions and find a balance between migration cost and overhead while coding.

Answer (score 3):

See [MySQL DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) - there is no syntax definition for an alias in DELETE.

Comment: While this is not entirely correct, it helped me to find the answer, so I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this query works:

```xml
<named-native-query name="FileSet.deleteByMemberId">
    <query>DELETE f FROM FileSet f WHERE f.file_id = :fileId</query>
</named-native-query>
```

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) only mention this far down the page:

> If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table: `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...`